# The date command do not convert to time stamp the format returned by date command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, busybox

the date command of linux return the following date format

```
root@root:~# date
Sat Jun 14 06:36:42 CEST 2014
```

The current date time stamp could be printed if I add +%s

```
root@root:~# date +%s
1402720624
```

Now If I want to print the time stamp of the date returned by the date command, I get the following error

```
root@Inteno:~# date -d"Sat Jun 14 06:36:42 CEST 2014" +%s
date: invalid date 'Sat Jun 14 06:36:42 CEST 2014'
```

How I can make the date return the time stamp of the date format `Sat Jun 14 06:36:42 CEST 2014` ?

**Note:** I m using date from BusyBox v1.19.4

Comment: working for me.version 8.4.

Comment: Working for me also. Date version : date (GNU coreutils) 8.13

Comment: could it be that you're running busybox, with its built in date, instead of a full blown date, like GNU date? From busybox I get the same error

Comment: I m using date from BusyBox v1.19.4

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on an Ubuntu14.04, having a German locale. Can you try `LC_TIME=C date -d"$(LC_TIME=C date)" +%s` ? Does it work?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately busybox's date has limitations but if you can consider using timestamps instead you can do:

```
TS=$(date '+%s')
date -d "@${TS}"
```

Still if CEST is your current local time, you can do:'

```
DATE=$(date)
date -d "$(echo "$DATE" | cut -d ' '  -f 2,3,4,6)" '+%s'
```

As removing the timezone would still apply.

Comment: Please check my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756916/the-date-command-do-not-convert-to-time-stamp-the-format-returned-by-date-comman#comment38414294_24756916) . Looks like its a problem with the locale.

Comment: @hek2mgl Does it apply with busybox's date? `busybox date ...`

Comment: This is still open.. But I don't expect busybox date much different from a *regular* GNU date

Comment: I have busybox's date and it doesn't accept formats like `Sat Jun 14 06:36:42 CEST 2014`.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I suggested to use `LC_TIME=C date` to produce the initial date. Then use the same env variable again to parse it .

Comment: I see. But running `LC_TIME=C busybox date` here produces an output of same format.

Comment: Oh I think now got it. You asked if I've used busy box on Ubuntu. No, I used bash and GNU date but I could reproduce the same behaviour with a German locale. Let me try with busybox ....

Comment: Tried it, you are right. The help page of busybox date clearly states it's limitations. Thanks for showing this! (my locale problem looked like related, but wasn't)

Comment: @hex2mgl No worries there :)